# HyperlinkedRelatedField not working with to_internal_value (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a HyperlinkedModelSerializer set up with a few references to other models using the HyperlinkedRelatedField.  This works just fine:

```
class LicenseSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    style = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
                                        view_name='styles-detail',
                                        queryset=Style.objects.all()
                                       )

    order = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
                                        view_name='orders-detail',
                                        queryset=Order.objects.all()
                                       )
```

But I need to do some data transformation on some of the other fields, so I override `to_internal_value`:

```
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data
```

At which point the HyperlinkedRelatedField no long works. I get an error saying:

`Cannot assign "'[hyperlinked identity url]'": "[Model.attribute]" must be a "[hyperlinked model]" instance.`

Which, at least to me, suggests the HyperlinkedRelatedField no longer works?

Here's a dump of the Serializer when it crashes:

```
LicenseAppSerializer(context={'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x03E9D870>}, data={'price': 0, 'style': u'http://localhost:8000/api/1/styles/69/', 'years': 30, 'order': 'http://localhost:8000/api/1/orders/44/', 'qty': 80}):
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='licenseapp-detail')
    start = DateField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    end = DateField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    price = DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    years = IntegerField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    qty = IntegerField()
    order = HyperlinkedRelatedField(queryset=Order.objects.all(), view_name='order-detail')
    style = HyperlinkedRelatedField(queryset=Style.objects.all(), view_name='style-detail')
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    return data
```

`Serializer.to_internal_value` validates the received data (`data`) and converts it into types that are useful on the ORM level.

For `HyperLinkedRelatedField`s it retrieves (via  `HyperLinkedRelatedField.to_internal_value`) the object that is being linked to. In your case, you directly passed unvalidated `data` which contained the URLs instead of objects. This might have worked if data contained only primitive types, but would still be insecure.

If you are about to do any transformations, retrieve the objects first:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    validated_data = super().to_internal_value(data)
    # Your transformations on validated_data
    return validated_data
```

Comment: Wonderful. thank you for the explanation.  Makes a lot more sense now.